Is Protista a kingdom just for unicellular eukaryotes that couldn't be classified under any other kingdom?
Is Kingdom Protista merely a "catch-all" classification for unicellular eukaryotes that do not belong to the kingdoms of Animalia, Plantae, or Fungi? Or does it possess specific criteria that organisms must meet to be classified within it? Furthermore, what are the distinguishing characteristics that unify this kingdom despite its apparent diversity, except being unicellular & eukaryotes?

Welcome to SE Bio! Please take the tour and look at the criteria for asking questions that are likely to get a helpful answer. Among these are doing some initial background research like googling your question. In this case, the wikipedia page for protists has the answer to your question as its second sentence.
